# Add an asterisk to the required fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a form field as shown below and others like that too.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-show="!role.vacancies">
  <label for="vacancies" class="col-md-3 control-label"> VACANCIES </label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input name="vacancies" type="text" id="vacancies" ng-model="Org.vacancies" placeholder="VACANCIES" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```

The Org variable is as follows:

```
var Org = {
        validate : {
                'planCode':{
                                'optional' : 'false', 
                                'validation' : 'required', 
                },
                'organizationCode':{
                                'optional' : 'false', 
                                'validation' : 'required', 
                },
                'vacancies':{
                                'optional' : 'false', 
                                'validation' : 'number required', 
                                'allowing' : 'range[1;100]', 
                },
                'planDate':{
                                'optional' : 'false', 
                                'validation' : 'required date', 
                                'format' : 'MM/dd/yyyy', 
                },
                'priorityCode':{
                                'optional' : 'false', 
                                'validation' : 'required', 
                },
                'description':{
                },
                'statusCode':{
                },
        }
  };
```

I want to add an asterisk to the fields in which the optional field of Org is "false" but not using ng-if.

Please help me out.Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ng-if`?

Comment: Using curlies like {{Ord.validate.vacancies.optional === 'false' ? '*' : ''}} in your template.

Comment: do you have a CSS class to show an asterisk?

Comment: Your `Org` variable is total mess, please copy and paste the actual code, not some broken mess which is impossible to read properly.

Comment: @techie_28: No I don't.

Comment: @Soviut: I want to use jquery.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Done

Comment: Still missing essential code: where are the form fields? How are the connected to `Org`?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: like vacancies there are other fields too.
In the controller the org is defined under $scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you want to add it via Jquery ? You can do this using CSS also.

```css
input:required {
  position: relative;
}
input:required {
  vertical-align: top;
  background: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/16/asterisk_orange.png') no-repeat center right;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  padding-right: 20px; /* so text doesn't overlap with asterisk mark image */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="form-group" ng-show="!role.vacancies">
  <label for="vacancies" class="col-md-3 control-label">VACANCIES</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input name="vacancies" type="text" id="vacancies" ng-model="Org.vacancies" placeholder="VACANCIES with required" class="form-control" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-show="!role.vacancies">
  <label for="vacancies" class="col-md-3 control-label">VACANCIES</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input name="vacancies" type="text" id="vacancies-1" ng-model="Org.vacancies" placeholder="VACANCIES not required" class="form-control">
  </div>
</div>
```